# Can I reuse agar in Petri dishes?

Tags: microbiology, growth-media

Can I simply re-melt agar in a contaminated Petri dish to use it again? I've tried searching for the answer on the Internet, but I was only able to find information about reusing Petri dishes themselves, not the agar in them.

Comment: reuse for what?, plant food, sure, for an experiment, no, spores are things.

Comment: @John Microwaving does not destroy the spores?

Comment: No, not just heating it enough to melt, many spores need prolonged heating to be destroyed  and some spores can survive anything short of incineration. Your not just talking about human dangerous spores, a plate can be contaminated by all kinds of spores.

Comment: Depends on what the dish is made of - plastic ones might well melt.

Comment: Is it a broth agar or other with some nutrients in it? If so, once used some (a small fraction or more depending on how heavy the growth was) will have been used up, and there will be an accumulation of metabolic byproducts, so newly plated growth may be affected. You also run the risk of not eliminating all microbial contaminants. If you're a hobbiest, it might not matter to you (eventually the agar will be useless), but if you're serious, the answer is to stick to accepted protocols.